# its continously showing Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> tried many things but still not working

Tags: reactjs

https://github.com/ranjit-sudo/React-Doubt

> Please go this repo to find the code as i am new and  not able to
> submit my question here beacuse of error in my question while
> reviewing it..
>
> I have continously trying to solve this issue of "Error: Invariant
> failed: You should not use outside a Router" but its not still it persists i tried wrapping my "App" component into BrowserRouter still it breaks also tried to wrap my "Link" component  in "Switch" it doesn't work.Someone  Please help me out..

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for all relevant code so that we may see what it's doing. Links out to external resources tend to decay and become irrelevant. I took a look at your repo and don't see an issue with the code. Try ensuring your development server is fully stopped (not running at all) and do a clean build and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your **index.js** file?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```